# Create a gridded dataset in sp and gstat - R

Tags: r, r-sp, gstat

I have trouble getting my data to create a grid using sp and gstat package in R. 
I have a relatively small data set with GPS coordinates and I want to interpolate my data and make a gridded map. My data is in a csv file and is currently not in a shapefile or raster.

I've so far been able to plot my data points with the "bubbles" function, and now I am trying to create a grid. 
But I constantly get this error:

> gridded(test_2) = T
>   suggested tolerance minimum: 0.75 
>   Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
>     dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant

I am not sure why the intervals are not constant, or how it might be possible to "manipulate" them to be. I have measured distances from shore from 0-1000 m, that I normalized to 0-1.

Any suggestions on how to make the intervals constant?

Thanks !!

Karen

Code example:

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
test_2_2 <- read.csv("test_2_2.csv")

summary(test_2_2)
      Lat             Long          Sample.id       Water.level      Temp          Salinity         Chl_a       
 Min.   :33.14   Min.   :-117.4   Min.   :  1.00   Bottom :34   Min.   :19.00   Min.   :30.43   Min.   :  7.57  
 1st Qu.:33.14   1st Qu.:-117.3   1st Qu.: 69.25   Surface:36   1st Qu.:24.50   1st Qu.:33.40   1st Qu.: 22.63  
 Median :33.14   Median :-117.3   Median :102.50                Median :24.70   Median :33.45   Median : 29.07  
 Mean   :33.14   Mean   :-117.3   Mean   : 95.54                Mean   :24.46   Mean   :33.34   Mean   : 30.15  
 3rd Qu.:33.14   3rd Qu.:-117.3   3rd Qu.:129.75                3rd Qu.:25.10   3rd Qu.:33.47   3rd Qu.: 35.53  
 Max.   :33.15   Max.   :-117.3   Max.   :153.00                Max.   :25.95   Max.   :33.94   Max.   :116.07  
                                                                                NA's   :1       NA's   :5       
    Nitrate      
 Min.   :0.1330  
 1st Qu.:0.4260  
 Median :0.5480  
 Mean   :0.8324  
 3rd Qu.:0.7970  
 Max.   :4.7700  
 NA's   :11      


coordinates(test_2_2) = ~Lat+Long
bubble(test_2_2, "Temp")

test_2 <- read.csv("test_2.csv") # Import grid data
names(test_2)
[1] "Dist" "Lat"  "Long"
coordinates(test_2) = ~Lat+Long
class(test_2)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
names(test_2)
[1] "Dist"
gridded(test_2) = T
suggested tolerance minimum: 0.75 
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

Comment: From your question it is not even clear which variable you want to interpolate.

Comment: Are the Lat and Long coordinates of `test_2` actually a regular grid? Also, I noticed that you set the coordinates, but did not project your data. Perhaps that is also a problem.